# Cordova (v3.0.0) CLI failing on Mac - no output for 'which android' command

Tags: android, macos, bash, cordova

All,

I am trying to upgrade to `Cordova v3.0.0` and have installed the `cordova` package from npm, have installed the latest Android SDK and ensured the necessary PATH variables are in place.

Also I can run `adb` and `android` commands from terminal, but I noticed that I don't get any output for `which android` command.

And the `which` not resolving I believe is the error I am getting when I try to do `cordova platform add android` in my newly created project. The error is:

```
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
Deleting project...
]
```

I have been poring over all the Google search results for this error and as to why `which android` does not resolve, but to no avail.

Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out finally !

I had included the platform-tools and tools like this:

```
PATH="~/android/sdk/tools:~/android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

And when I changed that to the below, it just started working...

```
PATH="/Users/<username>/android/sdk/tools:/Users/<username>/android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

So much for the `which` implementation in Mac. Hope this might helps someone starting with Mac like me.

Comment: Worked for me as well - OSX Mavericks 10.9.1